# Pairwise independence of sufficient statistics in exponential families

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, independence, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics

**tl;dr:** A simple argument seems to show that the sufficient statistics in a canonical exponential family are *necessarily* pairwise independent, which is clearly not true. So, what goes wrong in the derivation below?

**Derivation (updated).** This argument avoids reparametrization issues. Suppose we have an exponential family $\mathfrak{P}=\{p_{\theta}:\theta\in\Omega\}$ given by
\begin{align}
p_{\theta}(x)
&= h(x)e^{\theta\cdot x - A(\theta)},
\quad
x\in\mathbb{R}^{k}.
\quad (*)
\end{align}

Then obviously
\begin{align*}
p_{\theta}(x)
&= h(x)e^{-A(\theta)}\prod_{i=1}^{k}e^{\theta_{i}x_{i}}.
\end{align*}

We can assume $h(x)=1$ without any loss of generality (e.g. by absorbing $h(x)$ into the dominating measure). <s>Reparametrizing in terms of the sufficient statistics $t$,</s> 
We have the factorization $p_{\theta}(x)=f_{1}(x_{1})\cdots f_{k}(x_{k})$ (e.g. let $f_1(x_1)=e^{-A(\theta)}e^{\theta_{1}x_{1}}$ and $f_i(x_i)=e^{\theta_{i}x_{i}}$ for $i>1$). This factorization is enough to ensure that $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k}$ are independent.

Thus, the sufficient statistics in a canonical exponential family are always mutually independent. What goes wrong in this argument?

**Note.** There always exists a dominating measure such that $(*)$ holds, see Propsition~1.5 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215466759). The same author calls this a *standard exponential family*. For the curious, this question arose from trying to understand some of the arguments in this textbook.

(Update: @Henry below has a very simple counterexample that proves that this is definitely false.)

Comment: Exactly what theorem are you quoting where you write "this is enough to ensure ... independent"? Although you appear to have in mind one about factorization of a joint density, I don't see the Jacobian of the transformation from $x$ to $(t_1,\ldots, t_k)$ anywhere.

Comment: The $x$ themselves are the same across the $f_i(t)$, hence you need not have independence between the $t_i(x)$, which are just different functions of the same underlying $x$.

Comment: @whuber: That is indeed a flaw, thanks for pointing it out! Even so, there is a way around this, and independence still seems to persist. See my modified argument above. Regarding the theorem I am using: Not really a theorem, but once we have the factorization of a joint into the product $f_1\cdots f_k$, this implies independence (easy calculation, or see Dawid, 1979).

Comment: In your reformulation, Henry's answer no longer is a counterexample.  I will continue suggesting that you are playing fast and loose with the notation and with your application of this factorization. I think if you were to write things down carefully and consistently, the error would be prominently revealed.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure where the notation is fast and loose, but if you can point out any inconsistencies I'd be glad to rewrite the derivation with more consistent notation.

Comment: @Xi'an: Can you please elaborate? This would be really interesting to flesh out in more detail. In particular, are you saying that there exist probability measures for which $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$ does _not_ imply independence (the above standard ERF being an example)?

Comment: @Xi'an Has pointed out one place where your notation is problematic: by making $h$ disappear, you created the paradox.

Comment: Removed based on @Xi'an's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem with this "paradox" comes from absorbing $h(x)$ into the
>   dominating measure and then forgetting about the dominating measure.

The most common definition of a *probability density* is associated with a   measure that is a product measure, like the Lebesgue measure. In this case, it is straightforward to prove that $p(x,y)=p_X(x)p_Y(y)$ implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent:
\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(X\in A, Y\in B)&=\int_{A\times B} p_X(x)p_Y(y)\text{d}\lambda(x,y)\\&=\int_{A}\int_{B} p_X(x)p_Y(y)\text{d}\lambda(x)\text{d}\lambda(y)\\&=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)\end{align*}

This result does not, however, extend to arbitrary dominating measures. The fact that a density (i.e. Radon-Nikodym derivative) against an arbitrary measure $\lambda$ factorises as $p(x,y)=p_X(x)p_Y(y)$ (with $p_x$ and $p_y$ integrable against the projected measures $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$) does not make the components $X$ and $Y$ independent. It depends on the measure $\lambda$.

> "Independence as a product" is achieved in terms of probabilities or
>   measures, not in terms of densities.

A simple [counter-]example is made of the switch from the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_0$ to the new measure $$\exp\{\varrho xy\}\text{d}\lambda_0(x,y)$$ The distribution with density
$$p(x,y)=\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}\right\}$$
against this measure is the Gaussian distribution with *non-zero* covariance $$-\frac{\varrho}{1-\varrho^2}.$$

An even simpler [counter-]example [or re-expression of the above] is to switch from the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_0$ to the new (Gaussian) measure $$\frac{(1-\varrho^2)^{1/2}}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}+\varrho xy\right\}\text{d}\lambda_0(x,y)$$ and to consider the constant density $p(x,y)=1$ against this alternative dominating measure. We are again facing a distribution that is Gaussian with non-zero covariance but which has a product density.

Comment: In your example, neither $\lambda_0$ nor the new measure are _probability_ measures. The same problem arises in my derivation by absorbing $h(x)$ into the dominating measure. So to clarify: These counterexamples arise precisely because the underlying measure is not a probability measure. Or are there also counterexamples where the dominating measure is also a probability measure?

Comment: @JohnAustin: I do not understand the objection about the dominating measure not being a probability measure. This is not a counter-example, this is an explanation of why the notion of independence is impacted by both the density and the measure.

Comment: I believe I see the issue now. Please see my edits to your response for a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not true

Consider a sample of $n$ observations from a normal distributed random variable $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with unknown mean and variance, which is from an exponential family

- $\left (\sum x_i, \sum x_i^2\right)$ is a sufficient statistic
- $\sum x_i$ and $\sum x_i^2$ are not independent

Comment: I think the question was about the canonical sufficient statistics

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - if the canonical form of the likelihood is $\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right)^n \exp\left( \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}\sum x_i-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum x_i^2  - \frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} -\frac{\log(\sigma^2)}{2}\right)$ then I would have thought the canonical parameters would be  $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$ and  $-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$ and the corresponding sufficient statistics would be $\left (\sum x_i, \sum x_i^2\right)$.  But perhaps I have misunderstood

Comment: This looks correct to me. Such a simple counterexample, too. The question then remains: What is wrong with the derivation I gave above?